# How to use "vi -t" to find system call's source code? FreeBSD

Tags: vi, freebsd

My teacher's notes said

> "There is a tags file that can be built which will make finding things in the kernel source code easier. You can find source code for a function in the kernel source tree by using "vi -t" and the function name"

Such as:

```
#vi -t open
 can open the source code of open.
```

But I tried it on my FreeBSD 8.1. It fails...why? How can I configure it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate the tags file first with [`ctags(1)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ctags&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html).